# Converting between Word8 and Word16 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I am trying to to little endian conversion in haskell, so that I can turn a Word16 into two Word8 (for example 258 = 1*256 + 2, so result should be [2, 1]). I then pack the result into a ByteString.

I created the following code for this purpose:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits

getByte b num = shift (relevantBits b num) (shiftNum b)
    where bitMask b = sum $ map (2^) [8*b-8 .. 8*b-1]
          relevantBits b num = num .&. bitMask b
          shiftNum b = 8-8*b

encodeWord16 x = [getByte 1 x, getByte 2 x]

input :: Word16
input = 355

output :: [Word8]
output = encodeWord16 input
```

The function `getByte` gets Byte number `b` from a number `num`. The function `encodeWord16` uses this helper function to do the little endian conversion.

This however does not compile, I get the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Word8' with actual type `Word16'
In the first argument of `encodeWord16', namely `input'
In the expression: encodeWord16 input
In an equation for `output': output = encodeWord16 input
```

I (very unsystematically) tried to achieve the desired result by randomly distributing `fromIntegral` expressions, but obviously my understanding of the haskell type system is not good enough to solve this problem. Is there a systematic way to approach this problem?
Basically I want the function `encodeWord16` to have the type signature `Word16 -> [Word8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about extract those bytes directly? Like this:

```
encodeWord16 x = [ x .&. 0xFF, (x .&. 0xFF00) `shiftR` 8 ]
```

If you want the signature of `encodeWord16` be `Word16 -> [Word8]`, then add `map fromIntegral` before it, like this:

```
encodeWord16 :: Word16 -> [Word8]
encodeWord16 x = map fromIntegral [ x .&. 0xFF, (x .&. 0xFF00) `shiftR` 8 ]
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like a more efficient way to do it. I still have to apply `map fromIntegral` (see answer by András Kovács).

Comment: @Julian Yes, because if the type of `x` is `Word16`, then the type of `x .&. 0xFF` also will be `Word16`.

Comment: Is there a way to do Word8 -> [Word8]? Aka make them a list of bits

Comment: @astiefel Yes. However, I believe bit vector, such as [Data.BitVector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bv-0.3.0/docs/Data-BitVector.html), is a better option :-)

Answer (score 7):

`fromIntegral` can be used for conversion between various integral types.

```
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b

encodeWord16 :: Word16 -> [Word8]
encodeWord16 x = map fromIntegral [getByte 1 x, getByte 2 x]
```

It'd be nicer though to have `getByte` return `Word8`-s:

```
getByte :: Int -> Word16 -> Word8
getByte b num = fromIntegral $ shift (relevantBits b num) (shiftNum b)
    -- where ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of coding the conversion by hand, you might want to use the predefined functions to do so.

```
import Data.Word
import Data.ByteString.Builder
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (unpack)

encodeWord16 :: Word16 -> [Word8]
encodeWord16 = unpack . toLazyByteString . word16LE
```

Answer (score 1):

[binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) contains the following code:

```
-- Words16s are written as 2 bytes in big-endian (network) order
instance Binary Word16 where
    put     = putWord16be
```

(http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Binary.html#g:1)

```
-- | Write a Word16 in big endian format
putWord16be :: Word16 -> Builder
putWord16be w = writeN 2 $ \p -> do
    poke p               (fromIntegral (shiftr_w16 w 8) :: Word8)
    poke (p `plusPtr` 1) (fromIntegral (w)              :: Word8)
```

(http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Binary-Builder.html#g:5)

So you can just use it like this:

```
> encode (355 :: Word16)
"\SOHc"
> toLazyByteString $ putWord16be 355
"\SOHc"
> index (encode (355 :: Word16)) 0
1
> index (toLazyByteString $ putWord16be 355) 0
1
> index (encode (355 :: Word16)) 1
99
> index (toLazyByteString $ putWord16be 355) 1
99
```